# Is there a more practical way to solve this calculus question

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

$f:(-10,6]\to \mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=(x+4)(x+1)(6-x)$. If $m-n<0$, then what is the value of $mn$ for the maximum value of the integral $\int_{n}^m f(x)dx$?

I think we write explicitly function $f$ and take derivate find extremum values of $f$ then solve the question. Is there a more practical way to solve this question without write explicitly the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to calculate any integral.

Note, that $m<n$ and $\int_n^m f(x)dx = \int_m^n(x+4)(x+1)(x-6)dx$.

The function $g(x) = (x+4)(x+1)(x-6)$ is a cubic polynomial which is (you may make a sign test) positive for $x \in (-4,-1)$ and for $x> 6$.

Hence, for any $m<n \in (-10,6]$ the maximum value of the integral is attained for $m=-4, n=-1$.